# Anlytics API only returns number of users of the last two days

Tags: api, google-analytics

I don't know why, but in one of my analytics accounts, when I try to get the number of users by date y only can get the last two days, but I can retrieve the number of sessions correctly.

This issue I have only with one account, with the other can retrieve the data perfectly.

You know why?

Comment: Show more details please: an example of user report, your API request, ecc...

Comment: The request is exactly the same because is extracting the data with power bi. Maybe permissions thing?